# Missing symbols when importing `github.com/influxdb/influxdb/client/v2` package

Tags: go, package, influxdb

Setting up a web socket on google cloud in Golang, and import code that works fine on my local machine does not work on the cloud.

I have:

```
import "github.com/influxdb/influxdb/client/v2"
```

and have run

```
go get "github.com/influxdb/influxdb/client/v2"
```

Upon running go run server.go I get:

```
# command-line-arguments
./pi_server.go:47: undefined: client.NewClient
./pi_server.go:47: undefined: client.Config
```

Full code below, excluding const declarations and html:

```
package main

import (
    "flag"
    "html/template"
    "log"
    "net/http"
    "github.com/gorilla/websocket"
    "fmt"
    "net/url"
    "github.com/influxdb/influxdb/client/v2"
    "time"
)

var addr = flag.String("addr", "localhost:8080", "http service address")

var upgrader = websocket.Upgrader{} // use default options

func echo(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {

    //Influx init
    u,err := url.Parse("http://localhost:8086")
    checkError(err)
    influx_c := client.NewClient(client.Config{
            URL: u,
            Username: username,
            Password: password,
     })
    bp,err := client.NewBatchPoints(client.BatchPointsConfig{
        Database:  MyDB,
        Precision: "s",
    })
    tags := map[string]string{"my_sensor_id": my_sensor_id}
    //end influx init



    c, err := upgrader.Upgrade(w, r, nil)
    if err != nil {
        log.Print("upgrade:", err)
        return
    }
    defer c.Close()
    for {
        mt, message, err := c.ReadMessage()
        if err != nil {
            log.Println("read:", err)
            break
        }
        log.Printf("recv: %s", message)

        /*
            write to influx here
        */ 
        fields := map[string]interface{}{
            "random_int":   message,
            "other_stuff":  69696,
        }
        pt,err := client.NewPoint("test_collection", tags, fields, time.Now())
        checkError(err)
        bp.AddPoint(pt)
        influx_c.Write(bp)



        err = c.WriteMessage(mt, message)
        if err != nil {
            log.Println("write:", err)
            break
        }
    }
}

func home(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    homeTemplate.Execute(w, "ws://"+r.Host+"/echo", )
}

func main() {


    flag.Parse()
    log.SetFlags(0)
    http.HandleFunc("/echo", echo)
    http.HandleFunc("/", home)
    log.Fatal(http.ListenAndServe(*addr, nil))
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You local machine has a version of github.com/influxdb/influxdb/client/v2 before [this commit](https://github.com/influxdata/influxdb/commit/b0e9f7e844225b05abf9f4455229490f99348ac4). Your cloud server is fetching a more recent version of the package.

To fix the issue, run

```
go get -u github.com/influxdb/influxdb/client/v2
```

on your local machine to get the latest version of the package. Update the application code to use the new function and type names:

```
influx_c := client.NewHTTPClient(client.HTTPConfig{
        URL: u,
        Username: username,
        Password: password,
 })
```

Answer (score 0):

Nailed it, thanks! Also note from following code:

```
influx_c,err := client.NewHTTPClient(client.HTTPConfig{
    Addr: "http://localhost:8086",
    Username: username,
    Password: password,
})
```

They changed URL field to Addr, with is a string literal instead of a net/url object